# Conectar script php externo ao mysql de um server codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho um servidor XAMPP em um iMac OSX com um portal desenvolvido em codeigniter e gostaria de integrar ao Banco de Dados mySQL um script externo que, no momento, é executado via terminal e não está armazenando nada.

O script serve para pegar dados de um GPS. Segue o código:

```
<?php

require_once("SocketServer.class.php"); // Include the File
$server = new SocketServer("172.17.0.243",20490); // Create a Server binding to the given ip address and listen to port 31337 for connections
$server->max_clients = 10; // Allow no more than 10 people to connect at a time
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Run handle_connect every time someone connects
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); // Run handle_input whenever text is sent to the server
$server->infinite_loop(); // Run Server Code Until Process is terminated.


function handle_connect($server,$client,$input)
{
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"OK!");
}
function handle_input($server,$client,$input)
{
    // Mostra o que recebeu
    date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');
    $dataagora = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    echo "Data: ".$dataagora;
    echo "\nInput = ".$input;
    $trim = trim($input); // Trim the input, Remove Line Endings and Extra Whitespace.
    //echo "Trim = ".$trim;
    if(strtolower($trim) == "quit") // User Wants to quit the server
    {
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"Oh... Goodbye..."); // Give the user a sad goodbye message, meany!
        $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index); // Disconnect this client.
        return; // Ends the function
    }
}
```

**Eu tenho duas opções:**

**1** - Transformo em um controlador e deixo ele rodando 24hs de alguma maneira e conecto ao BD pelas funcionalidades do Codeigniter (mais difícil).

**2** - Conecto ele ao banco de dados do codeigniter e continuo rodando externamente via terminal. (Mais fácil)

Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Comment: Pra mim está incrivelmente confuso a sua questão de qualquer forma vou fazer algumas perguntas básicas: você quer conectar por socket em um endereço X, obter uma resposta dele e fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Eu gostaria mesmo é da opção 2, conectar ao banco de dados do meu XAMPP (aonde está o codeigniter). Será que é possível isso? Aonde eu deveria colocar o arquivo e quais os comandos para conectar o arquivo ao banco? Eu sei que hostname=localhost, database=smb, username=root e password=''. O que sugere?

Comment: então, mas justamente isso que estou questionando, pois você está dizendo: "quero conectar ele ao banco de dados do codeigniter" isso meio que "não existe". O banco do CI, é o banco do CI e pronto. O que você quer fazer realmente ou é fazer o CI conectar no databtase do GPS através do CI (alternar entre o database do CI e o do GPS), ou fazer alguma operação no GPS (através do socket, etc), e gravar isso no CI. Sério, está confuso. Se eu fosse você, reestruturava a pergunta e colocava de uma maneira clara o que você tem, o que você quer e de qual maneira.

Comment: O cenário é esse? Você tem um CI rodando em um servidor web e tem um script PHP rodando localmente na sua máquina. Você quer enviar os resultados desse script PHP para o BD aonde o CI está rodando? Se for isso, você pode fazer um controlador no CI que terá a função de receber os dados e armazenar no BD. E o seu script PHP envia os dados para esse seu controlador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi em seu código de exemplo você inclui um php que é uma classe para poder usar as funcionalidades da mesma.

Já pensou em transforma-la em uma library no CI, assim ficaria integrado ao Framework e usar todos os recursos já existentes, inclusive o acesso a este banco de dados.